# Apache-web server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I make some changes in httpd.conf for security issue.after that i restarted apache
but i was not able to access application .i thought catalina was not restarted then i restarted catalina but still i was not able to access application.then i reverted changes but still i am not able to access in catalina log i am able to see ajp port already in use.is it the cause because of which i am not able to access application?if not tell me the cause what i need to check so that i can access application.my apache version is 2.2.31 and my OS is AIX. kindly suggest any idea.

Comment: What's your configuration ? How many Tomcat you redirect to with your Apache ? You can't access your application but is your Apache Running ? On port 80 ? Please add information about your configuration or we won't be able to truly help and only make guesses.

Comment: tomcat version is 7.0.16 and apache version 2.2.31.only one tomcat i have redirected.my apache is running on listen port